# DRF UpdateAPI View returns "detail": "Not found."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When making PUT or PATCH to my DRF endpoint I get a 404 `"detail": "Not found."` response. I'm not sure what is causing the error, my view or serializer.

The documentation on DRF is a little lacking and there is no working example of a UpdateAPIView for me to reference.

Code:

urls.py

`path('api/update/job/<int:pk>/', views.UpdateJobView.as_view() ),`

serializers.py

```
class JobsUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designer_one = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
    designer_two = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class UpdateJobView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = JobsUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Job.objects.all()
        jobID = self.request.query_params.get('pk', None)
        if jobID is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id=jobID)
        else:
            return False
```

Do I need to modify my view to contain the `get_object` function?

`Django==2.1.3`
`djangorestframework==3.9.0`

Comment: We can't help much as it's not clear what you are trying to do by only looking at the provided code snippets.

Comment: @Linovia Apologies, I'm trying to pass updated values to Django from a Vue app. Ideally with a PATCH request but PUT will also be fine. Only one model Value will change per request.

Comment: still doesn't say much about what you are trying to do. Reading the code, it looks like you are trying to filter your job against a job id which seems a bit weird.

Comment: So in my frontend the user see's a list of Jobs and they have the ability to change the value of the fields in each Job, so when they update a field I pass the job ID to know what job is being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.request.query_params.get('pk', None)` is to get query parameters, not URL ones. Examples in the documentation filtering page are available for [query parameters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) and for [URL](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url).

You don't need to override `get_queryset` nor `get_object` in your case. Remove your `lookup_field` as it defaults to `pk` already and your custom `get_queryset`. Define a `queryset` instead and leave the remaining work to the default `UpdateView`:

```
class UpdateJobView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = JobsUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to have a look at the DRF source code too. The generic models methods and specifically the `get_object` are [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L77-L103)